# Monospace Fonts for Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, fonts, windows-store-apps

Are there any monospace fonts that are acceptable for use in Windows Store Apps??  I have read the guidelines, but there isn't mention of anything monospace.  Are there some built in fonts on Windows 8 that I can use instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The guidelines are just that... guidelines.  Microsoft won't reject your app because you don't use the fonts recommended in the docs.

There are many mono-spaced typefaces included in Windows 8.

- Consolas
- Courier New
- Lucida Console
- Lucida Sans Typewriter
- Segoe UI Mono

**Segoe** is one of the guideline recommended fonts, so the **Segoe UI Mono** should be a good pick.  **Consolas** is also a good choice.

You can also embedded other fonts in the application (if you have the license to do so.)

[FontSquirrel.com](http://FontSquirrel.com) , [DaFont.com](http://dafont.com),  [1001FreeFonts.com](http://1001FreeFonts.com) are some sites offer free, re-distributable fonts.
Just be sure that the font is **re-distributable** .

Comment: I actually can't find a copy of Segoe UI Mono on my machine, which was going to be my go to font.

Comment: According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/typography/fonts/windows_8_font_list), **Segoe UI Mono** seems never been included in any Windows version. But it was shipped by other Microsoft software: [Windows 7 is missing Segoe UI Mono](https://superuser.com/q/498864/503039). Monospaced fonts that are shipped with Windows since a long time are **Courier New** and **Lucida Sans Typewriter** ([Microsoft-Supplied Monospaced TrueType Fonts](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/90057/microsoft-supplied-monospaced-truetype-fonts))